# Uploaded Library to Bintray, but can't be resolved when used

Tags: android, maven, gradle, publishing

I'm following the tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582, to upload a library. All works well and it is on Bintray now as you could see in https://dl.bintray.com/elye-project/maven/.

However when I try to use the Library as per step 4 in the tutorial, I kept getting the following error.

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.elyeproj.libraries:analogtimerlibrary:1.0.0
```

I have check that in my project gradle I have put accordingly

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/elye-project/maven'
    }
}
```

And in my module gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.elyeproj.libraries:analogtimerlibrary:1.0.0@aar'
}
```

What's the possible problem? How could I resolve it?

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: Thanks @F43nd1r! That helps reaffirm the library has been published. I think I get what I did wrong, I put the build script repository.... instead of All Project repository. If that is what you did as well, feel free to post an answer, and I could give a tick to it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Found out apparently I place the maven repository on the wrong section. I place it at

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/elye-project/maven'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Instead of at

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/elye-project/maven'
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why it works for the sample library in the tutorial though.